# AngularJS - apply custom class directive to ng-repeat items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to set the width of a div dynamically via AngularJS.

```
<ul id="contents">
  <li ng-repeat="content in contents">
    <div class="content_right custom_width">
      <div class="title">{{content.title}}</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

with the following directive

```
myApp.directive("custom_width", function() {
  return {
    restrict:"C",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.css("width", 400);
    }
  }
});
```

But nothing is happening. I try to "console.log" within the "link:function.." but nothing gets printed. What am I missing here?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directive definitions use camelCase:

```
myApp.directive("customWidth", function() {
  return {
    restrict:"C",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.css("width", 400);
    }
  }
});
```

[Directive docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

In AngularJS, camel case (`lowerCamelCase`) is used when defining directives and accessing attributes (from within the directive), and snake case (`dash-case`- whatever you want to call it) is used for referencing the directives and/or attributes in HTML elements.

Comment: AFAIK `snake_case` is with underscores, it is often used in databases.